# invert mesh in three.js

Tags: three.js

How to invert a mesh using three.js

I had a mesh created using THREE.Mesh

```
var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( featurePts,extrudeSettings);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: color, wireframe: true, transparent: true } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,  mat );
```

But my shape looks inverted. Is there any way in Three.js to invert my shape?

`shape` used above is a list of `THREE.Vector2`

```
var featurePts = [];
featurePts.push(new THREE.Vector2 (550,107));
```

[image: expected not in 3d form]

[image: current output from Three.js]

Comment: Have you tried inverting the order of the `featurePts` array instead?

Comment: yes i tried that. But no luck.

Comment: have a look at this http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/core/Shape.js.html

Comment: particularly which method?

Comment: Wait. When you say inverted... what do you mean exactly? Upside down?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean it looks inside out, try reversing your normals.

Comment: I dont have much idea about three.js could you tell how?

Comment: From what I see from your code, since you are adding points to create a shape and then extrude that shape, try adding the points in reverse order. In your code you don't specify normals but I assume that ExtrudeGeometry calculates some for you. So if you reverse the order of points then the calculated normal will also be the opposite.

Comment: mrdood suggested the same thing. my bad. Can you post some more code or an image explaining what is expected and what you get?

Comment: I would say it is rotated. Even though you shouldn't have to, try adding a rotation on the y-axis for 180 degrees.